Android composition with specific Config (Locale)
Assume I want to have a Column of three texts and want each component (Text) to use different Locale so R.strings is read from different strings file.
Example:
Column {
    // wrap for english - expect "Hello"
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.hello)
    )

    // wrap for spanish - expect "Hola"
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.hello)
    )

    // wrap for italian - expect "Ciao"
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.hello)
    )
}

How can I achieve different Locale per Component?
